# Python: printing search indexes from xml file to xml file

Tags: python, xml

I wrote code that from XML file find Indexes I'm looking for. That indexes I'm looking for are writen in data.txt file. To open data.txt file I all ready have code `with open("data.txt") as in_file:`)...`k=[int(number, 16) for number in data]`. now I just need to all indexes(in data.txt) print me in output file(output.xml. I was thinking to use for loop but i don't now where.

DATA.TXT:

```
'3001','1018','1200'
```

CODE:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import serial as ser
tree = ET.parse('master.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


with open("data.txt") as in_file:
    data = in_file.read().strip().replace("'", "").split(",")
    k=[int(number, 16) for number in data]

for MagicNumber in root.findall('MagicNumber'):
    print MagicNumber.tag,':', MagicNumber.text
print''

for FileInfo in root.find('FileInfo'):
    print FileInfo.tag,':', FileInfo.text
print''

for DeviceInfo in root.find('DeviceInfo'):
    print DeviceInfo.tag,':', DeviceInfo.text
print''

for DummyUsage in root.find('DummyUsage'):
    print DummyUsage.tag,':', DummyUsage.text
print''

for ObjectDictionary in root.find('ObjectDictionary'):
    print ''
    print ObjectDictionary.tag,':', ObjectDictionary.get('name'), ObjectDictionary.text

    for Record in ObjectDictionary.iter('Record'):
        if Record.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Record name: ', Record.attrib['name']
        elif Record.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            ObjectDictionary.remove(Record)              

    def remove_self(target):
        target.getparent().remove(target)
    for Variable in ObjectDictionary.iter('Variable'): 
        if Variable.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Variable name: ', Variable.attrib['name']
        elif Variable.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            remove_self(Variable)

    for Array in ObjectDictionary.iter('Array'):
        if Array.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Array name: ', Array.attrib['name']
        elif Array.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            ObjectDictionary.remove(Array)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EDSFile>
    <MagicNumber>-1616</MagicNumber>
    <FileInfo>
        <FileVersion>1</FileVersion>
        <FileRevision>0</FileRevision>
        <ModificationTime>12:19PM</ModificationTime>
    </FileInfo>
    <DeviceInfo>
        <ProductNumber>0</ProductNumber>
        <RevisionNumber>0</RevisionNumber>
        <OrderCode>Order code</OrderCode>
        <BaudRate_10>0</BaudRate_10>
        <BaudRate_20>0</BaudRate_20>
        <BaudRate_1000>0</BaudRate_1000>
        <Granularity>0</Granularity>
    </DeviceInfo>
    <DummyUsage>
        <Dummy0001>0</Dummy0001>
        <Dummy0002>1</Dummy0002>
        <Dummy0003>1</Dummy0003>
    </DummyUsage>
    <ObjectDictionary>
        <Group name="MandatoryObjects">
        </Group>
        <Group name="OptionalObjects">
            <Array name="Store Parameter Field">
                <Index>4112</Index>
                <ObjectType>8</ObjectType>
                <Variable name="Number of Entries">
                    <Index>4112</Index>
                    <Subindex>0</Subindex>
                    <DataType>5</DataType>
                    <AccessType>0</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <DefaultValue>3</DefaultValue>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="Save all Parameters">
                    <Index>4112</Index>
                    <Subindex>1</Subindex>
                    <DataType>7</DataType>
                    <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="Save Communication Parameters">
                    <Index>4112</Index>
                    <Subindex>2</Subindex>
                    <DataType>7</DataType>
                    <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="Save Application Parameters">
                    <Index>4112</Index>
                    <Subindex>3</Subindex>
                    <DataType>7</DataType>
                    <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
            </Array>
            <Variable name="COB-ID EMCY">
                <Index>4116</Index>
                <Subindex>0</Subindex>
                <DataType>7</DataType>
                <AccessType>0</AccessType>
                <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                <DefaultValue>$NODEID+0x80</DefaultValue>
                <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
            </Variable>
            <Variable name="Inhibit Time Emergency">
                <Index>4117</Index>
                <Subindex>0</Subindex>
                <DataType>6</DataType>
                <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                <DefaultValue>0x01F4</DefaultValue>
                <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
            </Variable>
            <Variable name="Producer Heartbeat Time">
                <Index>4119</Index>
                <Subindex>0</Subindex>
                <DataType>6</DataType>
                <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                <DefaultValue>0x000003E8</DefaultValue>
                <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
            </Variable>
        </Group>
        <Group name="ManufacturerObjects">
            <Array name="Error_Log_Time_Hours_PRODUCER">
                <Index>8257</Index>
                <ObjectType>8</ObjectType>
                <Variable name="Time_Last_Error_(h)_4">
                    <Index>8257</Index>
                    <Subindex>5</Subindex>
                    <DataType>6</DataType>
                    <AccessType>0</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <DefaultValue>0x00</DefaultValue>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="Time_Last_Error_(h)_10">
                    <Index>8257</Index>
                    <Subindex>11</Subindex>
                    <DataType>6</DataType>
                    <AccessType>0</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <DefaultValue>0x00</DefaultValue>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="Time_Last_Error_(h)_20">
                    <Index>8257</Index>
                    <Subindex>21</Subindex>
                    <DataType>6</DataType>
                    <AccessType>0</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <DefaultValue>0x00</DefaultValue>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
            </Array>
            <Variable name="Test_DOUT_Value">
                <Index>9229</Index>
                <Subindex>0</Subindex>
                <DataType>3</DataType>
                <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                <DefaultValue>0</DefaultValue>
                <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
            </Variable>
            <Variable name="PDO_RxLdtp2">
                <Index>9253</Index>
                <Subindex>0</Subindex>
                <DataType>3</DataType>
                <AccessType>1</AccessType>
                <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                <DefaultValue>0x00</DefaultValue>
                <PDOMapping>1</PDOMapping>
            </Variable>
        </Group>
        <Group name="ParametersObjects">
            <Array name="Test mode configuration">
                <Index>12319</Index>
                <ObjectType>8</ObjectType>
                <Variable name="Number of entries">
                    <Index>12319</Index>
                    <Subindex>0</Subindex>
                    <DataType>3</DataType>
                    <AccessType>0</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <DefaultValue>9</DefaultValue>
                    <LowLimit>1</LowLimit>
                    <HighLimit>64</HighLimit>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="Duty cycle change slope">
                    <Index>12319</Index>
                    <Subindex>7</Subindex>
                    <DataType>3</DataType>
                    <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <LowLimit>0</LowLimit>
                    <HighLimit>32767</HighLimit>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="Stator frequency change slope">
                    <Index>12319</Index>
                    <Subindex>8</Subindex>
                    <DataType>3</DataType>
                    <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <LowLimit>0</LowLimit>
                    <HighLimit>32767</HighLimit>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="Slip frequency change slope">
                    <Index>12319</Index>
                    <Subindex>9</Subindex>
                    <DataType>3</DataType>
                    <AccessType>2</AccessType>
                    <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
                    <LowLimit>0</LowLimit>
                    <HighLimit>32767</HighLimit>
                    <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
                </Variable>
            </Array>
        </Group>
    </ObjectDictionary>
</EDSFile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: `ObjectDictionary.iter('Variable')` actually iterates the whole tree of node ObjectDictionary. The matches of `Variable` in your example is 4 level deeper (see the xml dump below).

```
<Group name="OptionalObjects">
  <Array name="Store Parameter Field">
    <Index>4112</Index>
      <ObjectType>8</ObjectType>
        <Variable name="Number of Entries">
          <Index>4112</Index>
          <Subindex>0</Subindex>
          <DataType>5</DataType>
          <AccessType>0</AccessType>
          <ObjectType>7</ObjectType>
          <DefaultValue>3</DefaultValue>
          <PDOMapping>0</PDOMapping>
        </Variable>
```

The solution: To remove such elements, you should call `Variable.getparent().remove(Variable)`.

As there are many places in your code need to remove elements from an iteration result. I'd suggest define a helper function and call the function to do the job.

```
def remove_self(target):
    target.getparent().remove(target)

# YOUR CODE
for Variable in ObjectDictionary.iter('Variable'): 
    if Variable.find('./Index').text == str(i):
        print 'Variable name: ', Variable.attrib['name']
    elif Variable.find('./Index').text != str(i):                    
        remove_self(Variable)
```

Comment: I have just one more modification to do and I don't want to asking a new question..I have .txt file where are writen all Indexes I'm looking for. By accident I forget to change `if Array.find('./Index').text != str(i):` in `if Array.find('./Index').text == str(i):` (same for the Variable and Record), Python Shell actually print me like I want to, but output file is the same like input file (master.xml).
If I write it like I want in first `if Array.find('./Index').text == str(i):` print me just the first writen index from data.txt.
I was thinking to use for loop but I don't know how.
any idea?

Comment: In the question I add NEW XML "working" code.
In data.txt is writen '3001','1018','1200'

Comment: @user3639326 Put complex things in comment is not a comfortable way for us to help you. Please organize your question as a new question and minimize the problem you have.

Comment: I have .txt file with few number's of index inside `'3001','1018','1200'`. the program must read me this few numbers and print me Variables, Records and Arrays below right group in ObjectDictionary (like now with one index). 

In my question I add NEW XML where I modify it to open .txt file and read number's inside it. now I just don't know how to make it that print me out like I said above. In for loops for variables,arrays and records I tried add if and elif statement but it's not do what I want. probably I should use for loop but I don't know how.
I hope you understand now.

Comment: @user3639326 Really do not know what you want to do, if you want to print a node, you can use `print(ET.tostring(Variable, pretty_print=True))`, if you want to split `'3001','1018','1200'`, then use `line.split(',')`. You might update your question, which is better asking something in a comment.

Comment: On short I want to print me this three numbers of index  `'3001'`(Index),`'1018'`(Index),`'1200'`(Index) at once(now print me just one index). this tree numbers take from .txt file.

Comment: i change question. I hope you understand now.

Comment: @user3639326 Are you asking to build a new xml document by iterating the whole xml document several times? Here is a great place to start http://lxml.de/tutorial.html PS: I can try to answer your questions, but you'd write code youself.

Comment: program remains completely the same except instead of one index we're looking for 3 or 4 or more. just here is the difference.